# Search entity by tag and return all other tags as well in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

In my case an entity is a recipe and a tag an ingredient. I want to search by ingredient and return all recipes containing the ingredient and return all other ingredients as well. In my case ingredients can have synonyms.

First, here are my tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ingredient` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `synonym_group` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredient` (
  `recipe_id` int NOT NULL,
  `ingredient_id` int NOT NULL,
  `alternative_ingredient_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_optional` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipe_id`,`ingredient_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is the query I've come up with:

```sql
SELECT 
  r.name, 
  i_all.name

FROM
  recipe r
  
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        recipe_id 
    FROM 
        ingredient i 
        JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id 
        LEFT JOIN ingredient i_syn ON i.synonym_group = i_syn.synonym_group 
    WHERE i.name = 'Asd' OR i_syn.name = 'Asd'
) i ON i.recipe_id = r.id 

JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON i.recipe_id = ri.recipe_id 
JOIN ingredient i_all ON ri.ingredient_id = i_all.id
```

I feel like this query is very complicated for what I want to do and there is a much simpler way. Mainly it feels weird that I have to specify the search term twice in the query.
Right now, if I only filter by `i.name = 'Asd'` I won't find any synonyms and if I only filter by `i_syn.name = 'Asd'` I won't find anything if the search term has no synonyms. Removing the `distinct` doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there just no better way or am I thinking too complicated?

Example data for ingredients:

| id | name | synonym_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bell Pepper | 1 |
| 2 | Capsicum | 1 |
| 3 | Egg | NULL |
| 4 | Sugar | NULL |

Comment: I am unclear how synonyms work for example if an item has no synonyms how does ingredient look? Sample data as text would help clarify.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've added sample data for the ingredients. Synonyms just have the same value for `synonym_group`. It's mostly to account for different spellings of ingredients rather than different words (the actual ingredients are not in English).

Comment: What is provided parameter? Does this provided parameter is an ingredient, and the needed output is complete ingredients list where each separate ingredient is included into at least one the same recipe with ingredient-parameter?

Comment: @Akina The input parameter is an ingredient (ingredient.name) and the desired output is all recipes that include the input ingredient and all ingredients for each recipe returned.

Comment: @sollniss Thank you for accepting my answer but I really think you should accept P.Salmon's answer. It meets your criterion of just passing your search term once and it appears to be more performant.

Comment: Alright I changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that -

> Removing the `distinct` doesn't seem to change anything.

which suggests your test data is inadequate.  The following illustrates the importance of `DISTINCT` in your current query. Given your ingredients listed above and the below recipes -

| id | name | type | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | recipe 1 | type | comment |
| 2 | recipe 2 | type | comment |
| 3 | recipe 3 | type | comment |
| 4 | recipe 4 | type | comment |
| 5 | recipe 5 | type | comment |

| recipe_id | ingredient_id | alternative_ingredient_id | is_optional |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | NULL | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | NULL | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | NULL | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | NULL | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | NULL | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | NULL | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | NULL | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | NULL | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | NULL | 0 |
| 5 | 4 | NULL | 0 |

Your inner query -

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    recipe_id 
FROM 
    ingredient i 
    JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id 
    LEFT JOIN ingredient i_syn ON i.synonym_group = i_syn.synonym_group
WHERE i.name = 'Bell Pepper' OR i_syn.name = 'Bell Pepper';
```

returns -

| recipe_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

but if you drop the `DISTINCT` it returns -

| recipe_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 5 |

If you drop `DISTINCT` but add an additional join predicate to stop it LEFT JOINing to itself you get the desired result -

```sql
SELECT
    recipe_id 
FROM 
    ingredient i 
    JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id 
    LEFT JOIN ingredient i_syn ON i.synonym_group = i_syn.synonym_group AND i.id <> i_syn.id
WHERE i.name = 'Bell Pepper' OR i_syn.name = 'Bell Pepper';
```

More important than the query is the need to have the inverse index on the junction table -

```
ALTER TABLE recipe_ingredient
    ADD INDEX IDX_ingredient_recipe (ingredient_id, recipe_id);
```

Your current query can be improved by nesting the ingredients list in another derived table and modified to allow for searches based on multiple ingredients with a best match type ranking. This is a bit of a hybrid of your original query and the solution proposed by P.Salmon -

```sql
SELECT r.name, i.name
FROM (
    SELECT recipe_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ri.ingredient_id) AS num_matched
    FROM recipe_ingredient ri
    JOIN (
        SELECT COALESCE(i2.id, i1.id) AS ingredient_id
        FROM ingredient i1
        LEFT JOIN ingredient i2 ON i1.synonym_group = i2.synonym_group
        WHERE i1.name IN ( 'capsicum', 'onions' )
    ) all_syn ON ri.ingredient_id = all_syn.ingredient_id
    GROUP BY recipe_id
    ORDER BY num_matched DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10
) mr
JOIN recipe r ON mr.recipe_id = r.id
JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
JOIN ingredient i ON ri.ingredient_id = i.id
ORDER BY mr.num_matched DESC, r.name ASC;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88357195a59ccfe1cff2510f39f3d1f0)

This query does not rely on the synonym_group being the id of one of its members.

Note the GROUP BY... ORDER BY... and LIMIT clauses on the middle layer query. With my test dataset of 39,774 recipes, 6,702 ingredients and 428,249 the server-side execution time is 13-16ms

Here's a little [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd92ca4c342b9db7f8fd5d6ce024502a) to illustrate how the innermost query works to get the ingredients list.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I didn't test all usecases regarding the `distinct`, so I forgot the reason why I acutally added it. Are there any differences between using `distinct` versus having another condition in the predicate of the left join?

Also thanks for the suggestion of the ranking. That was probably what I was going to add to the query next. Do you think there are any major differences between yours and @P.Salmon 's version?

Comment: I am going to do more testing against a much larger dataset to make sure my current tests are valid. There is no measurable difference between the DISTINCT and the additional join predicate. I just think the additional predicate makes the intent clearer to understand. That ranking can easily be applied to P.Salmon's query in the same way.

Comment: @sollniss How are you assigning the synonym_group? Is it the lowest ingredient.id in the group or is that just a coincidence in your example?

Comment: For now I'm assigning it manually as the lowest id in the group but preferably it should work with randomly assigned ids as well (as long as they are not overlapping). The select case @P.Salmon 's query would prevent me from using random ids, right?

Comment: Well spotted. I didn't notice this at first and was confused when the two queries returned wildly different result sets. After resetting all groups to use an id of one of the members all was fine. Interestingly, the initial improved performance observed with P.Salmon's query disappears and reverses for some cases as the dataset grows.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Thinking about it, requiring the group id being equal to one of it's member's id doesn't seem too limiting of a design choice if I can get twice the performance. With my current dataset the execution time of P.Salmon's query is about 6ms with 774 rows examined while the original one takes 12-13ms with 9748 rows examined. Do you think maybe adding an index somewhere could improve performance?
I'm planning to use the query for real-time searching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240676/discussion-between-nnichols-and-sollniss).

Answer (score 2):

I would establish all the ingredients in groups and not in groups where not in groups simplify by setting a group to ingredient id then join to recipe to get distinct recipe then the tables can be simply joined. This way the code doesn't care which ingredient or member of group you search on.

```
drop table if exists ingredient,recipe,recipe_ingredient;
CREATE TABLE `ingredient` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `synonym_group` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ;
insert into ingredient (id,name ,synonym_group) values
(1,'egg',null),(2,'bell pepper',10),(3,'capsicum',10),(4,'sugar',null),(5,'chilli pepper',null);

CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredient` (
  `recipe_id` int NOT NULL,
  `ingredient_id` int NOT NULL,
  `alternative_ingredient_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_optional` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipe_id`,`ingredient_id`)
) ;

insert into recipe_ingredient values
(1,1,null,null),(2,2,null,null),(2,5,null,null),(2,4,null,null),(3,3,null,null);

insert into recipe (id, name) values
(1,'stew'),(2,'nei'),(3,'three');

select r.id,r.name,ri.recipe_id,ri.ingredient_id,i.name
from recipe_ingredient ri
join recipe r on r.id = ri.recipe_id
join ingredient i on i.id = ri.ingredient_id
join
(
select distinct ri.recipe_id rid
from recipe_ingredient ri
join
    (
    select i.id ,sg
    from ingredient i 
    join
    (
    Select case 
        when i.synonym_group is not null then i.synonym_group 
        else i.id
        end as sg
    from ingredient i where i.name = 'capsicum' 
    ) t on 
    t.sg = i.synonym_group or 
    t.sg = i.id
) u on u.id = ri.ingredient_id
) v on v.rid = ri.recipe_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=879979bde1118b6e8fb1acf6d090204c

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this version tomorrow including all the extra stuff I need for the query.